# Magnetic static field simulation software to model metals in Earth's magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields, simulations, metals

I need to model the effect of steel or iron objects of a given shape disturbing Earth's magnetic field like shown in the pic below. The software, providing a solution, should be free and open source. Ideally, hosted on GitHub and written in Python (it's still OK otherwise).

[image: sphere]

Earth's magnetic field is assumed to be homogeneous, static, and vector-like (no curvature).

Input:

- Earth's magnetic field vector (direction and strength).
- A list of metal objects. Each object is defined by the *material* (steel, iron, etc.), *shape*, *size*, and *position* (x, y, z) on the map.

The output should be a tensor **B[x, y, z]** providing the magnetic field strength at XYZ coordinates.

Applications: testing a magnetometer (what resolution/sensitivity should it have to pick Earth's mag field deviation), gathering data to train a NN to identify the object given the data (later on) from a magnetometer and a GPS tracker.

What I've already found:

- https://github.com/magpylib/magpylib/discussions/560 same question of mine asked on MagPyLib. They do not solve such things.
- https://github.com/cmt-dtu-energy/MagTense is a promising start but with few stars. Not sure if they model my cases.
- https://quickfield.com/advanced/block_pm_ferromagnetic.htm but I don't need magnets
- https://www.femm.info/wiki/ComputationalMagneticsLinks an extensive list of available magnetic  field solvers, free and paid, dead and alive. It's like searching a needle there.

Comment: Aside from the soft python requirement, it looks like Comsol or Elmer would be useful tools in this case (one is commercial, the other is freeware).

Comment: Comsol does not fit the open source requirement. Although they do not cover the impact of metals on a static magnetic field in their examples, I'll give Elmer a try, thanks.